# convert binary to bitmap using memory stream

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I wanna convert binary array to bitmap and show image in a `picturebox`. I wrote the following code but I got exception that says that the parameter is not valid .

```
  public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
    {
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] pData = blob;
        mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
        mStream.Dispose();
        return bm;

    }
```

Comment: Why are you copying the byte array?  Why not just do `using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(blob);) {return new Bitmap(mStream);}`

Comment: You want to convert image to stream and store to database as varbinary?

Comment: no i wanna read it from db and dsplay it in picbox

Comment: this may help you http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/03/save-and-retrive-binarydata-from.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It really depends on what is in `blob`. Is it a valid bitmap format (like PNG, BMP, GIF, etc?). If it is raw byte information about the pixels in the bitmap, you can not do it like that.

It may help to rewind the stream to the beginning using `mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` before the line `Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);`.

```
public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
{
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         mStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
         mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

         Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
         return bm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this rejected edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3181577). From the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx) it looks like he is right.

Comment: How can this work when the MS doc is clearly stating "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap."? Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.6.2#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_IO_Stream_
Also, this answer does not work in my case, where I use the Image for Telerik Report. Here I get a rendering error when I dispose the stream.

Answer (score 5):

Don't dispose of the MemoryStream.  It now belongs to the image object and will be disposed when you dispose the image.

Also consider doing it like this

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(blob);
var img = Image.FromStream(ms);
.....
img.Dispose(); //once you are done with the image.
```

Comment: i trace my code i get argumanexeptioninvalid at this code Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);

Comment: This is not true! The stream and the byte information do not "belong to the image object". The stream *must* even be disposed of to not get memory leaks.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I've worked with this a lot and I can tell you that disposing the memory stream will cause problems.  Don't believe me?  Try it for yourself.

Comment: We're not talking WPF where ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Check this out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/5884995d-23ac-4fd9-bae3-878b0da70f76

Comment: Well, I tried disposing the stream after loading the image from it. It works fine.

Comment: I'm always disposing MemoryStream and after this I'm using Bitmap. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.MemoryStream mStrm = new System.IO.MemoryStream(your byte array);
Image im = Image.FromStream(mStrm);
im.Save("image.bmp");
```

Try this. If you still get any error or exception; please post your bytes which you are trying to convert to image. There should be problem in your image stream....

Comment: i do it too but i get parameter is not valid exception

Comment: Ok friend, can you please post your bytes converted into string here?

Comment: How do the image bytes get into the database? Are you *really* sure that the bytes in the database represent an image in format PNG, GIF, BMP, etc.? If not, you can not use the `Bitmap` constructor.