# The parameter IS NOT valid. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When i'm using this following code i got this error:

```
The parameter IS NOT valid.
```

This is the code:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(CType(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value, Byte()))
        info.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(ms)
    End Using
```

Im using the access database with ole object.

Comment: what is in `DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value` ?

Comment: In that row i have a picture

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13913447/2882256

Comment: Right, an OLE object is *not* an image.  Google ".net read image from access database" for relevant hits.

Comment: thank u sir i will search that.