# Display A Picture From Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I have a datagridview and when I click inside, it opens another form with the information that is inside the datagridview.

[image]

In my Access database I have OLE Object with a picture (bitmap) and I want to display that in the form `info` too.

This is the code that I have to get the info when I click in the datagridview:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick

Dim curForm As Form = New Form
With curForm
info.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
info.TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value
info.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value
info.TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value
info.TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value


info.Show()
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [**PLEASE do not make dups**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474386/the-parameter-is-not-valid-vb-net). You asked a question not long ago dealing with this.