# Image.MemoryStream : Parameter not valid

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

When I'm trying to retrieve my image by combo box there show the massage . **Parameter not valid**
I was try many way but problem is same ..

Every time I run the code below, I get same massage.

```
    private void cBoxSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con = ConnectionController.GetInstance().GetConnection();
            con.Open();
            com = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE ProductName = '" + cBoxSearch.Text + "' ", con);

            myReader = com.ExecuteReader();
            product prod = new product();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                prod.proid = myReader[0].ToString();
                prod.prodname = myReader[1].ToString();
                prod.proMdl = myReader[2].ToString();
                prod.serialN = myReader[3].ToString();
                prod.byibgPr = myReader[4].ToString();
                prod.sellPr = myReader[5].ToString();
                prod.quantity = myReader[6].ToString();

                tbxProductID.Text = prod.proid;
                tbxName.Text =prod.prodname;
                tbxModel.Text = prod.proMdl;
                tbxserial.Text = prod.serialN;
                tbxbyingprice.Text = prod.byibgPr;
                tbxSellingprice.Text = prod.sellPr;
                tbxQuantity.Text = prod.quantity;

                prod.imgg = (byte[])(myReader[7] );

                if (prod.imgg == null)
                {
                    pBX.Image = null;

                }
                else
                {
                    MemoryStream mstrm = new MemoryStream(prod.imgg);
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mstrm);

                }

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            com.Cancel();
            con.Close();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the StackTrace of the exception?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Please tell me where is the SQL injection vulnerability ....

Comment: Haindl sir I dont know how to do it  ...

Comment: May I enter `1' or 1 = 1; drop table Stock ' --` into your form?

Comment: so what is the solution bro ??

Comment: Use SQL Parameters -  its hard to find a DB related post here which doesnt show how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to consult this question:

[convert binary to bitmap using memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913353/convert-binary-to-bitmap-using-memory-stream)

Also, it might depend on DBType of the 8th column of the query.